# Difficulties with Axios - Cors setup in React - Flask project

Tags: reactjs, flask, redis, axios, flask-cors

im facing some problems while setting up the authentication functionality of my react - flask application.

[This is what my headers look like and what the error says.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoEI7.jpg)

I am running server sided sessions that i am using redis for.
After the POST request i want to return a cookie in the future, because of that i need Credentials to be true.

Thats my frontend:

[httpClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yUiD.jpg)

[post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X93xd.jpg)

And the backend:

[Both versions dont work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goIb9.jpg)

Axios is installed and flask-cors as well.

I already spent a view hours in trying to solve this problem mostly in vary with the post() headers and/or the CORS() settings but this is still what gave me the most promising result.

I also did read a lot of posts about this topic but couldn't find a solution.

Thank you very much and any advice will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Update:

Hey guys, 

thanks for your super quick responses. 

My problem was, that i tried to split my app in several small apps as we know it from django. For some reason this made me a hard time to implement the CORS setup. Now that i put it back to just a view files the problems disapeared. 

I will now have to split it up step by step from a working state to track down to where the problem begins.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you need to add CORS preflight by OPTIONS method reply in backend other than access control headers.

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*',);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Mode,access-control-allow-origin');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
  return res.end()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that

you should add a reverse proxy in the frontend, even though the flask is configured.

I got a similar problem and the cors problem comes from **browser**, it seems your frontend is in localhost:3000, and the backend is in localhost:5000, you send the request directly to the backend like localhost:5000/user/login in your error picture which is the cause.

you should send all the request to a temp endpoint like localhost:5000/api/xxx, then the proxy send the request to localhost:3000/xxx, that's the reverse proxy thing.

I am using webpack, for local development, this is my configure, and this do the exactly thing I have mentioned

```
devServer: {
      static: './dist',
      port: 7789,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: env.BACKEND_URL,
          pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '',
          },
        },
        secure: false,
      },
    },
```

I believe other bundle tools like vite should have similar configurations

Before:

localhost:3000 -> localhost:5000

Now:

localhost:3000 -> localhost:3000/api(reverse proxy) -> localhost:5000